# Consulta SQL. Joins

Tags: sql, select, join

Colocar valor de una tabla2 en una consulta a tabla1.

Tengo una consulta en SQL

```
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by IdCertificado order by FechaCambio) Consecutivo,
upper (IdCertificado) IdCertificado , IdTipoSolicitud ,
cast (FechaCambio AS date) FechaCambio,
Observaciones , NumFolio, IdEmpleado  from Tabla1 with(nolock)
```

y me arroja esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]  }

tengo una tabla2 la cual contiene esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo hacer que dentro de mi consulta en vez de arrojar el IDTipoSolicitud puedo colocar la DescripcionSolicitud.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar [Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), que permite combinar registros de una o más tablas, puedes probar con un [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

Para tu consulta debes agregar también [alias](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp), quedando más o menos de esta forma:

```
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a.IdCertificado order by a.FechaCambio) Consecutivo,
upper (a.IdCertificado) IdCertificado , a.IdTipoSolicitud ,
cast (a.FechaCambio AS date) FechaCambio,
a.Observaciones , a.NumFolio, a.IdEmpleado, b.DescripcionSolicitud as Solicitud
   FROM Tabla1 as a
       INNER JOIN tabla2 as b ON a.IdTipoSolicitud = b.IdTipoSolicitud
```